# accessing data in android from assets vs internal storage. Which is faster or better?

Tags: java, android, performance

Which is faster to read data from file in android, a file from assets folder or a file from internal storage?

Comment: why don't you make a test app and see it yourself? Actually I don't think that it's matter of performance at all since assets size is limited by max size of APK file, and if you are talking about performance, then you are going to use large ammount of files/space, which is not ok for assets from this point of view

Comment: yes , i think i should check for large files with test app

Comment: how large are the files in total? if they are too large, you have no choice to use assets

Comment: total 25 megabytes in size

Comment: ok, in this case assets is an option. Personally I think that assets will wort slower since they are a part of an APK file, and have to be extracted from it before used (as I think)

Comment: i too think that its slower because assets are part of an APK. so i will copy files to internal storage and will use from there

Comment: I think it's a good idea if the performance of file I\O matters so much

Comment: i think, once the application is installed, the APK is extracted into the `/data/app.private.folder` so `raw` and `assets` are already extracted? are not they? if you copy from `assets` to internal storage this is just a duplicate and waste of space **-unless data will be modified later-** as `assets` and raw are READONLY so, yes that would be a good reason, otherwise i don't think performance is an issue.